# How to get URI on imageview with Glide

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I'm using 'Glide' to load image from a server to an ImageView. I would like to know if it's possible to extract that URI from the imageview itself.

```
ImageView contentImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contentImage);
```

........

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(contentImageUrl)
.crossFade()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.into(contentImage);
```

My aim is to share the image in Imageview.
How to get URI on imageview with Glide?

```
Uri uri = ??????????????

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: You can get image uri from filepath. doesn't that suffice ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to get Uri change ur `Glide` implementation to:

```
Bitmap bitmap;

 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(contentImageUrl)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        // you can do something with loaded bitmap here
                        contentImage.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        bitmap= resource;
                    }
                });
```

Now call the method;

```
    //get URI from bitmap
   Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);
```

in `getImageUri` function:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), inImage, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

You need to add permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also for runtime permission: Api>=23

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

Comment: Such an error has occurred:

java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                      at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:480)
                      at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:470)
                      at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:442)
                      at com.uruker.ibrahim.project.ContentDetail.getImageUri(ContentDetail.java:654)
at com.uruker.ibrahim.project.ContentDetail$13$1.onResourceReady(ContentDetail.java:494)

Comment: at which line? did u add the permission?

Comment: Yes permissions added.
Also, there are no permissions errors in other events.

Comment: try moving this line:`Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);` outside of `onResourceReady` method check the edit

Comment: The same error
This is on line with error:     return Uri.parse(path);

Comment: Try changing this line:`String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), inImage, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");`

Comment: That's great, this solution worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The addNewPostImage is the image view;
the image is inserted with Glide library

```
Imageview addNewPostImage = findviewbyid(R.id.addNewPostImage);    
Bitmap bitmap;
EditText addNewPostWebLink = findviewbyid(R.id.addNewPostWebLink);
 
   private void getUri() {
    String imageUrl = addNewPostWebLink.getText().toString().trim();
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            //.fitCenter()
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    // you can do something with loaded bitmap here
                    //bitmap = resource;
                    addNewPostImage.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
    postImageUri = getImageUri(NewPostActivity.this);
    Toast.makeText(this, Objects.requireNonNull(postImageUri).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Since the image bitmap has been set on resource body we call the getImageUri() which first get the bitmap out of the Image, compresses it and stores the image. Once stored it returns the stored path. the image is stored in the external storage

```
private Uri getImageUri(NewPostActivity newPostActivity) {
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) addNewPostImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(newPostActivity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```