# Share image from Glide

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-image, android-glide, android-sharing

I have Activity with `ViewPager` and appropriate adapter with images, so I can slide them left or right. Images are loaded with Glide library from the API response, they are saved with `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)`. So I wonder how can I share them with native Android share? I need the path to the image which I can't find.

Here is the code:

**Adapter:**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_preview_item, container, false);

    String imageUrl = mImageObjectList.get(position);

    currentImage = view.findViewById(R.id.ivCurrentImage);

    GlideApp.with(mContext)
            .asDrawable()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(currentImage);

    container.addView(view);
    return view;

}
```

And I have `shareSelectedImage()` method in adapter which will be called from main activity when user clicks on share:

```
public void shareSelectedImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    String shareBody = "Text body";

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ?????);
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    listener.shareImage(intent);

}
```

So I don't know how to get URI from current image in adapter from Glide on question mark place? Any advice? Or any other idea on how to implement this?

Comment: According To me Save The Image Then Share it

Comment: But the image is already saved by the Glide, do you know how to get it?

Comment: If You Want to Share Image With Other App You want to save The Image In Device

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Obviously you don`t get the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So Explain The Question

Comment: did you solve your question

Answer (score 0):

First, get the selected image
In your adapter:

```
currentImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent DisplayImage=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DisplayImage.class);
            DisplayImage.putExtra("ImageUrl",imageUrl);
            context.startActivity(DisplayImage);
        }
    });
```

Share image with display image activity, then load this image in an ImageView using Glide. Then save this image to the device and get the path of the saved image, which you can share with other applications.

Or

[See This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200448/how-to-get-uri-on-imageview-with-glide)

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.0'

```
var mImgBitmap: Bitmap? = null

Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load("url").into(
    object : CustomTarget<Bitmap?>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap?>?) {
                mImgBitmap = resource
                imgView.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
    })

val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
share.type = "image/*"
val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    mImgBitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
    requireActivity().contentResolver,
    mImgBitmap, "Title", null)
val imageUri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is text")
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"))
```